# Now that we have our first wiki answer should all the other answers be combined into one?

Tags: discussion, answers, community-wiki

This is the first [question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/q/141/5) with wiki answers.

For a  wiki

> Voting on a community wiki post does not affect the author's reputation.
> ([ref](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts))

As such there really is no need to keep all of the information spread across multiple answers.

Should the policy of this site be to combine the answers into one?

---

If the authors care about it being know they answered with the information earlier, they can edit the single wiki answer to note such.

Answer (score 11):

On MathOverflow, I believe the policy is that "big list" questions should be community wiki but that, to the contrary, each answer should contain only *one* answer.  The advantage of this is that reputation-irrelevant voting can then be used to sort the answers according to their interest and relevance to the question.  I would suggest adopting such a policy here as well.

Answer (score 6):

The most recent science/research/academic site to be launched in the SE network before this one, was Matter Modeling Stack Exchange, which has a tag called "**one-topic-per-answer**". On questions with that tag, users are highly discouraged from discussing more than one topic in each answer, and the Meta discussion associated with that is [here](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/5). Users there are also discouraged from writing more than one answer to such questions, in order to avoid single-user-domination of a thread, but that site also doesn't use the Community Wiki feature for such questions either (which seems to be what we're doing here at [ProofAssistants.SE](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/).

Here are the 5 top questions (by score) with that tag, since I think it may be illuminating to see how the tag works there:

- [Supercomputers around the world](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1515/5)
- [What are some recent developments in density functional theory?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/392/5)
- [What is a good programming language for matter modeling?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/365/5)
- [What are the types of charge analysis?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/1439/5)
- [Is there a free package with robust CASSCF functionality?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/414/5)

Answer (score 1):

It's important to mention that **if** the Q&A is going to be a FAQ (which may not be the case for the linked example in this question) then **all** the answers are combined into the highest voted answer (after discarding or fixing downvoted answers). Here is an example of a [FAQ on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/282094) about CW posts.

If you don't have 10K on that site you can [view this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwZtr.jpg).